# Finding height of a $k$-ary tree

Tags: proof-explanation, trees

I found a formula for the height of a $k$-ary tree in a book "*An Introduction to Data Structures and Algorithms*" by J. A. Storer.

It computes the height as follows (page 224, chapter 7):

$$
\begin{align}
h &= \log_k(L(n)) \\
  &= \log_k\left(\frac{(k - 1) n + 1}{k}\right) \\
  &= \log_k\left((k - 1) n + 1\right) - 1 \\
  &= \left(\log_k(k-1) + \log_k(n)\right) - 1\\
  &= (1 + \lfloor \log_k(n) \rfloor) - 1 \\
  &= \lfloor \log_k(n) \rfloor
\end{align}
$$

Here $L(n)$ is the number of leaves in a complete $k$-ary tree of $n$ vertices.

Unfortunately I can't see the logic between steps 3 and 4:
$$
  \log_k\left((k - 1) n + 1\right) - 1 = \log_k((k-1) n) - 1
$$

Essentially it claims that $$\log_k(x + 1) = \log_k (x)$$

What do I miss here?

Answer (score 0):

After some thought I still think it is a mistake to drop $+1$, but the final result should be correct, if we do following:

$$
\begin{align}
  \log_k\left((k - 1) n + 1\right) - 1 &= \log_k\left((k-1)\cdot n \cdot (1 + \frac{1}{(k-1)n})\right) - 1\\
  &= \log_k(k-1) + \log_k{n} + \log_k (1 + \frac{1}{(k-1)n}) - 1 \\
  &= \log_k\left((k-1)\cdot \left(1 + \frac{1}{(k-1) n}\right)\right) + \log_k n - 1\\
  &= \log_k\left(k - 1 + \frac{1}{n}\right) + \log_k n - 1\\
  &= \lfloor \log_k(n) \rfloor
\end{align}
$$

The last step is valid, because we know that

$$
0 < k - 1 + 1/n \leq k
$$